# Sending a JSON Object via AJAX POST Request to Rails Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax

I thought this would be straightforward since I constantly use AJAX to update models via an actual form that exists in the DOM but when trying to send a JSON object I am running into problems trying to get it to work.

I know there are a lot of similar questions but none seem to be concrete in terms of what the JavaScript should be and how the request should be parsed by the controller, I have tried every variation I can think of but I still can't retrieve the data from the request.

**JS**

```
var form_data = JSON.stringify(quote);

$.ajax({
    url: '/quotes/save_draft',
    data: { params: form_data },
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

For the `data` attribute I have tried

```
data: { params: form_data },
data: form_data,
data: quote,
```

**Rails Controller**

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params.inspect
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json].inspect
```

but I still can't get a property of the original JSON object to print successfully, e.g. `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json][:params][:payment_term]`, with `[:params]` being the top level attribute of the JSON object.

The output of `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json][:params][:payment_term]` looks like a url encoded string rather than a JSON object but if I try using `JSON.parse(params[:_json])` I just get an an error which is `TypeError (can't convert String into Integer)`.

Any ideas? I know it must be some combination of what I have above and I'm sure I've tried them all but I must not have or I'm trying something completely irrelevant.

**Full Controller**

```
def save_draft
  if request.post?
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "\n\n"
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json]
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json][:form_data]
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json][:form_data][:payment_term]
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "\n\n"

    render :text => '1'
  else
    render :text => '0'
  end
end
```

The current error from that is to do with the `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params[:_json][:form_data]` line, it's a no method error because of a nil object.

This is the output of `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info params.inspect`

```
{"action"=>"save_draft", "_json"=>"form_data=%7B%22line_items%22%3A%5B%7B%22contract_term%22%3A12%2C%22product%22%3A%222-Pair+EFM+off-net%22%2C%22site%22%3Anull%2C%22quantity%22%3A1%2C%22setup_cost_each%22%3A1500%2C%22setup_cost%22%3A1500%2C%22rental_cost_each%22%3A240%2C%22rental_cost%22%3A240%2C%22is_ad_hoc%22%3Afalse%2C%22default_setup%22%3A1500%2C%22default_rental%22%3A240%2C%22default_contract%22%3A12%2C%22fixed_initial_cost%22%3Afalse%2C%22price_list_item_id%22%3A194%2C%22info%22%3A%22Provides+up+to+10Mb%2Fs+of+symmetric+Ethernet+connectivity+with+a+6-hour+fix+SLA.%22%7D%5D%2C%22partner_id%22%3A125%2C%22raised_by%22%3A940%2C%22approval_required%22%3A0%2C%22payment_term%22%3A%22Monthly%22%2C%22message%22%3A%22%22%2C%22scope_of_work%22%3A%22%22%2C%22internal_message%22%3A%22%22%2C%22partner_ref%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ccs%22%3A%22%22%2C%22project_requires_coordination%22%3A0%7D", "controller"=>"quotes"}
```

Comment: Just use simple `data: { form_data : form_data }`. Can you please post your controller?

Comment: it is just a guess but give it a try: change  `contentType: 'application/json'` to  `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",   dataType:"json",'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've implemented both, the controller is quite simple for now, I've updated the question.

Comment: what if you simply log this params[:params]

Comment: @Athar - it just seems to be blank. I think you only get the `_json` hash when using the `application/json` content type

Comment: can you do simply p params in your controller and see how params are coming in server logs please and it would be great if you share too in question

Comment: I've updated the questions @Athar which should hopefully help, as you'll see it just looks like a url encoded string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83760/discussion-between-athar-and-martincarlin87).

Comment: Did you validate the JSON you sent to the server. Put data into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mpdunson, I did try linting my json already and that seems fine.

Comment: What's the json object client-side? I believe you linted it. I just want to see why you get the TypeError (can't convert String into Integer)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment there @mpdunson, Athar has been helping me and I think that I was getting that error further down in my controller and I just didn't notice the line number, I think we may have solve it now but thanks for trying to help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/quotes/save_draft',
    data: quote,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      #your call 
    },
    error: function() {
      #show error
    }
});
```